# Why MySQL (MariaDB) took over 3 minutes to count records using the following query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm looking for a reason and suggestions.
My table have about 1.4Million rows and when I run following query it took over 3 minutes. I added count just for showing result. My real query is without count.

```
MariaDB [ams]> SELECT count(asin) FROM asins where asins.is_active = 1 
and asins.title is null and asins.updated < '2018-10-28' order by sortorder,id;

+-------------+
| count(asin) |
+-------------+
|      187930 |
+-------------+


1 row in set (3 min 34.34 sec)
```

Structure

```
id int(9) Primary
asin varchar(25) UNIQUE
is_active int(1) Index 
sortorder int(9) Index
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Query with EXPLAIN

> MariaDB [ams]> EXPLAIN SELECT asin FROM asins where asins.is_active = 1 and asins.title is null and asins.updated < '2018-10-28' order by sortorder,id;

[image]

Comment: You do not need `order by` and you probably need an index on (asins.is_active, asins.updated)

Comment: Please run your query with the word EXPLAIN before select and post the output...

Comment: If is_active only contains 0 and 1 then what is the point of having a separate index for that column?

Comment: @stephen I have added the EXPLAIN results.

Comment: You say "real query is without..." -- Then give us the real query.  _Any_ change, even a trivial change, can make a huge difference in performance considerations.

Answer (score 2):

The database is scanning all the rows to answer the query.  I imagine you have a really big table.

For this query, the `ORDER BY` is unnecessary (but it should have no impact on performance:

```
SELECT count(asin)
FROM asins 
WHERE asins.is_active = 1 AND
      asins.title is null AND
      asins.updated < '2018-10-28' ;
```

Then you want an index on `(is_active, title, updated)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an index on is_active and updated.  So that index is going to be scanned (like a table scan, every record in the index read), but since title is not in the index, there is going to be a second operation which looks up title in the table.  You can think of this as a join between the index and the table.  If most of the records in the index match your conditions, then the join is going to involve most of the data in the table.  Large joins are slow.

You might be better off with a full table scan if the conditions against the index are going to result in a large number of records returned.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110707/how-can-i-force-mysql-to-ignore-all-indexes for a way to force the full table scan.  Give it a try and see if your query is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
INDEX(is_active, updated),
INDEX(is_active, sortorder, id)
```

And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

With the first of these indexes, some of the filtering will be done, but then it will still have to sort the results.

With the second index, the Optimizer *may* chose to filter on the only `=` column, then avoid the sort by launching into the `ORDER BY`.  The risk is that it will still have to hit so many rows that avoiding the sort is not worth it.

What percentage of the table has `is_active = 1`?  What percentage has a null `title`?  What percentage is in that date range?

Comment: - From 1.4 Million less than 15,000 is_active = 0 rest are 1
- I don't need title condition in query. If I remove title condition 100% of data will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a compound index, and part of it is range based, you want the range based part first.

So try the index (updated, is_active, title)

This way updated becomes a prefix and can be used in range queries.